# From editor to web page in fewest possible steps

Tags: firefox, pseudocode, software-design, filezilla, server-communication

Currently I use FileZilla, FireFox and Sublime 3. Steps between editing and seeing result:

- while (!allFilesSaved) { click; Ctrl-S; }
- while (!foundFileZilla) Alt+Tab OR clickIcon;
- while (!filesHighlighted) highlightFiles;
- Enter OR dragWithMouse;
- while (!foundFireFox) Alt+Tab OR clickIcon;
- while (!atCorrectPage) locatePage;
- if (wasAlreadyAtPage) F5;

That's at least 4 steps, assuming I have one unsaved file and have it as the current tab in Sublime, and also that the page doesn't autorefresh. How can I minimize the number of actions required?

Comment: Are you wanting suggestions on a better workflow?  Or suggestions on how to automate those steps?

Comment: I suppose better workflow follows automation. I want automation.

Comment: Have you looked at AutoHotkey?  It may do what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started using rsub with Sublime, and I absolutely love it. If you have ssh access, this could be a great solution.